# How to search for a particular pattern in a log file and count the number of matches?

Tags: linux, grep

In a very large log file I have entries like :

> FLOW ENTERING
>   somecompany.somepackage.datacontrol.provider.DataProvider@**c37ae61**.release()

The only change between what differs between entries is the string after the `@` and before `.release()`(The bolded portion).

There are other entries like the following which needs to be discarded in the search:

> FLOW ENTERING
>   somecompany.somepackage.datacontrol.provider.DataProvider@**c37ae61**.somethingelse()

So my search pattern should end with *`.release()`*.

How can I know the number of such occurrences in the log file(the number of matching lines) and also print out all the matching patterns?

P.S: I am using Linux environment.

Comment: You should clarify, what you want to count: The number of matching lines or the number of occurrences of each unique string between `@` and `.release()`.

Comment: @neocrow I want to count the number of matching lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `grep -c` option is exclusive - it's not possible to combine the -c option with another option to output matching lines ***AND*** a count. So using tee outputs the matches **AND** write the matches to a temporary file then count the lines in the file.

```
grep 'FLOW ENTERING.*release()' k  | tee /tmp/grep.tmp && wc -l /tmp/grep.tmp
```

Comment: What is the tee command doing here? Can you put some explanation?

Comment: tee takes the output (in this case from grep) and outputs it to the screen AND writes the output to a file /tmp/grep.tmp (so that wc can count the number of matches).

Answer (score -1):

you can use 
`grep '.release()' file|wc -l`